# Determining student grade based on criteria rowwise

Tags: r

I would like to find out whether a student is “PASSED” or “FAILED,” we have to apply the following criteria:

If the student has scored greater than 200 as total marks and scored greater than 33 in all subjects, then the student is “PASSED.”

If a student has scored less than 33 in 1 or 2 subjects and total marks are greater than 200, the student has got “ER” (Essential Repeat).

If the student has scored less than 33 in more than 2 subjects or less than or equal to 200 as total marks, then the student is “FAILED.”

```r
df <- data.frame(
  student = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  subject1 = c(40, 50, 60, 70, 80),   
  subject2 = c(35, 45, 55, 65, 75),  
  subject3 = c(38, 48, 58, 68, 78),   
  subject4 = c(33, 34, 35, 36, 37),  
  subject5 = c(42, 52, 62, 72, 82) 
)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(test = apply(across(-student),
                      1, 
                      function(x) case_when(sum(x) > 200 & sum(x > 33) == 5 ~ 'PASSED',
                                            sum(x) > 200 & sum(x < 33) %in% c(1, 2) ~ 'ER',
                                            TRUE ~ 'FAILED')))

  student subject1 subject2 subject3 subject4 subject5   test
1       a       40       35       38       33       42 FAILED
2       b       50       45       48       34       52 PASSED
3       c       60       55       58       35       62 PASSED
4       d       70       65       68       36       72 PASSED
5       e       80       75       78       37       82 PASSED
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code ```sum(x) > 200 & sum(x < 33) %in% c(1, 2) ~ 'ER' ```

Comment: True. Will fix it.

Comment: Is there anyway that the above result can be obtained without using ```apply```

Comment: Possibly, yes. Any specific reason why you don‘t want an apply solution?

Answer (score 0):

Compare `rowSums` with the respective achievements and add `+ 1` to the boolean. `replace` incrementally for additional criteria. Gives `1, 1, 2, 3, 2` which allows you to subset a vector of `c('FAILED', 'PASSED', 'ER')`.

```
df$achv <- c('FAILED', 'PASSED', 'ER')[(1 + (rowSums(df[s] < 33) <= 2)) |> replace(rowSums(df[s]) <= 200, 1) |>
                                         replace(rowSums(df[s]) > 200 & rowSums(df[s] < 33) %in% 1:2, 3)]
df
#   student subject1 subject2 subject3 subject4 subject5   achv
# 1       a        0        0        0       33       42 FAILED
# 2       b       50        0       48       34        0 FAILED
# 3       c       60       55       58       35       34 PASSED
# 4       d       70       65       68       36        0     ER
# 5       e       80       75       78       37       82 PASSED
```

Note that I designed different data below to match all the criteria.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(student = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), subject1 = c(0L, 
50L, 60L, 70L, 80L), subject2 = c(0L, 0L, 55L, 65L, 75L), subject3 = c(0L, 
48L, 58L, 68L, 78L), subject4 = 33:37, subject5 = c(42L, 0L, 
34L, 0L, 82L), achv = c("FAILED", "FAILED", "PASSED", "ER", "PASSED"
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```